# Connecting to a TTY from another computer

Tags: remote-access, tty

How do I access one of my TTYs from a computer on my home network?

For example, if my Ubuntu PC is running, and I want to access it's terminal from my Mac or Windows PCs that are on the same network.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from using `screen` you could use `linuxvnc` ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/linuxvnc.1.html)), a "VNC server to allow remote access to a tty". It can grab a TTY session and display it for use in a VNC window. Install it via apt:

```
sudo apt-get install linuxvnc
```

Once that is done, fire it up: (root access is required to grab TTYs)

```
sudo linuxvnc X
```

Where 'X' is the TTY # you want to grab. You could do this in a SSH session if you don't have physical access to the server. `linuxvnc` should indicate that it's listening on port 5900. Now connect with a VNC Viewer of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Install SSH server on the Ubuntu machine, then use an SSH client on Windows or Mac.

```
sudo install ssh
```

To connect from Mac I believe you may be able to use a command line client:

```
ssh my.ubuntu.box -u myusername
```

To connect from Windows you can use a GUI client, such as PuTTY.

(if you want to connect to an *existing TTY*, e.q. to start a session on the Ubuntu box locally, then walk to your Windows machine and connect to the same session from there then you need to use `screen` command in combination with SSH access. See `man screen` for more details)